# IntelliSense doesn't work properly for python in C# Project- Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, ironpython, ptvs

I have project that in VS is a C# project, but inside of it I have many IronPython sources. Out of box PTVS is highlighting syntax and IntelliSense is working with System modules. 
But I also have some assemblies (properly linked by references to the project); C# can use them, and they also work in IronPython (scripts are working). However, IntelliSense doesn't autocomplete or resolve objects in the editor. 
I thought that maybe IronPython in PTVS didn't see my libraries so I added them to IRONPYTHONPATH and after it + clr.AddReference. I can use them in interactive console, but no luck with the editor. In Settings I set all interpreters to IronPython only.

Comment: do you have xml/documentation files for your assemblies? visual studio needs to read those to display intellisense.

Comment: This are Windows Azure SDK files, so I have not only DLLs but also XML files with whole information. I tried to add this libraries to GAC and noticed that some of them are in it already, but IntelliSense don't sugest them.

Comment: This may have been due to a couple of bugs in PTVS. Try with the latest version and see if they've been resolved (and if not, feel free to files issues directly on http://pytools.codeplex.com/).